# Can't update after NIC Teaming/Bonding Linux Server

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, network-bonding

So, I'm a noob when it comes to Networking on Ubuntu. I created a bond/NIC Teaming on my Ubuntu Desktop for the 2 NIC cards that I have on it, but I'm unable to resolve DNS names. This is making my desktop unable to update or upgrade itself. What's weird is that I can ping 8.8.8.8, but I'm just not able to resolve hostnames such as google.com.

> /etc/network/interfaces.d
>
> auto ens3 iface ens3 inet manual
> bond-master bond0
>
> auto eno1 iface eno1 inet manual
> bond-master bond0
>
> auto bond0 iface bond0 inet static
> address 172.20.0.101
> gateway 172.20.0.1
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> dns-nameservers 202.151.64.140 8.8.8.8
> slaves ens3 eno1
> bond-mode 2
> bond-miimon 100
> bond-lacp-rate 1

[Testing Outside Conenection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPV1H.png)

Comment: I'm not sure how you set this up, but this link has some good information regarding NIC bonding plus screenshots.  see if anything in there helps.  https://www.tecmint.com/configure-network-bonding-teaming-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

So, just in case someone wants the answer. I was able to figure it out. If you upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 you'll have to use netplan to bond your interfaces versus ifenslave.

The yaml file can be found in /etc/netplan/01-network-manger-all.yaml

Here is my example

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        ens3:
           dhcp4: no
        eno1:
           dhcp4: no
    bonds:
        bond0:
            dhcp4: yes
            interfaces: [ens3, eno1]
            addresses: [172.20.0.101/24]
            parameters:
                mode: balance-xor
                primary: ens3
```

The literature can be found @ https://netplan.io/examples/

Hope this helps.
Wanting to rack up some points here in StackExchange as well.